# MVC The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Okay, this is driving me crazy.

I have this project, and I am MONTHS without touching the `FeedController`. Everything was working fine.
Then, I opened the `FeedController` to change some code inside an action and for some reason, VS2010 crashed. Okay, VS already crashed before, nothing unusual.

So I restarted VS, and mysteriously, the `FeedController` started to give *"404  The resource cannot be found"* error.

So I checked `Global.asax`, `Web.Config`, StartURL, all stuff people recommend. Can't get it to work. If I call `/Feed/Index`, It Works! But `/Feed/` just gives me the error.

Changed the name of the entire controller to `ShitController` and It just WORKS PERFECT! Somehow, the project decided that "Feed" is some kind of "curse word".

Cleaned solution, `/bin/` restarted vs dev server, restarted computer and it is just broker forever.

I'm starting to think this is a MVC3 serious BUG.

Anyone?

I'm getting crazy. I should go for a walk, maybe :)

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "XBLContentDetailsLocale",
    "XBLContent/Details/{guid}/{locale}",
    new { controller = "XBLContent", action = "Details"},
    new { guid = @"[0-9|a-z|\-]{36}", locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "XBLContentDetails",
    "XBLContent/Details/{guid}",
    new { controller = "XBLContent", action = "Details" },
    new { guid = @"[0-9|a-z|\-]{36}" }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    "XBLContentDaysLocale",
    "XBLContent/{days}/{locale}",
    new { controller = "XBLContent", action = "Index" },
    new { days = @"[0-9]", locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "XBLContentDays",
    "XBLContent/{days}",
    new { controller = "XBLContent", action = "Index" },
    new { days = @"[0-9]" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FeedRouteFull",
    "Feed/{action}/{sort}/{locale}",
    new { controller = "Feed", action = "GameAddons" },
    new { sort = @"[a-z|A-Z]+", locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FeedRouteSort",
    "Feed/{action}/{sort}",
    new { controller = "Feed", action = "GameAddons", sort = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { sort = @"[a-z|A-Z]+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "FeedRoute",
    "Feed/{action}",
    new { controller = "Feed", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Locale",
    "{locale}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    new { locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ControllerLocale",
    "{controller}/{locale}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", locale = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "ControllerActionLocale",
    "{controller}/{action}/{locale}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", locale = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { locale = @"[a-z|A-Z]{2}-[A-Z|a-z]{2}" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**UPDATE:**
I commented all the routes leaving only the default one, and the error still exists.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the whole controller. Only changed the Arcade action and commented the "oldcode":

```
public class FeedController : Controller
{
    XBLContentContext db = new XBLContentContext();

    private int activemenu = 4;

    private const int QT_FEED = 12;

    public ActionResult Index(string locale)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            locale = "en-us";


        ViewBag.Title = "Xbox LIVE Feeds";
        ViewBag.Description = "Xbox LIVE Feed generator. Configure and add it to your favourite feed reader.";
        ViewBag.Keywords = "xbox, live, tools, feed, syndication, rss, atom";

        ViewBag.ContentType = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ContentType)).Cast<ContentType>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = (v == ContentType.Arcade),
            Text = v.ToString().ToSentence(),
            Value = v.ToString()
        });
        ViewBag.SortBy = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortBy)).Cast<SortBy>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = (v == SortBy.OfferStartDate),
            Text = v.ToString().ToSentence(),
            Value = v.ToString()
        });

        ViewBag.Regions = (from x in GlobalVariables.Regions
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Selected = (x.ID.ToLower() == locale),
                               Text = x.Country,
                               Value = x.ID.ToLower()
                           }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AllDownloads(string sort, string locale)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var region = "All Regions";

        var qry = from c in db.XBLRegionalContents.Include("Region").Include("Content")
                  where c.PublishDate <= today
                  select c;

        var qry2 = from c in qry
                   group c by c.ContentId into grouped
                   let maxdate = grouped.Max(x => x.PublishDate)
                   select new
                   {
                       Key = grouped.Where(x => x.ContentId == grouped.Key && (x.PublishDate == maxdate)).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Value = grouped.Where(x => x.ContentId == grouped.Key).Select(x => x.Region)
                   };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            qry2 = from c in qry2
                   where c.Value.Any(x => x.ID == locale)
                   select c;

        var model = qry2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.PublishDate).Take(QT_FEED).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) && model.Count() > 0)
            region = model.FirstOrDefault().Key.Region.CountryEnglish;

        ViewBag.Language = locale;
        ViewBag.FeedTitle = "XBLTOOLS - Latest Content";
        ViewBag.FeedDescription = String.Format("{0} - {1}", region, DateTime.Now);

        return View("GlobalFeed", model);
    }

    public ActionResult FullGames(string sort, string locale)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var region = "All Regions";

        var indie = ContentType.IndieGames.ToString();
        var qry = from c in db.XBLRegionalContents.Include("Region").Include("Content")
                  where c.Content.RelatedGameId == null && c.Content.FileSize > 0
                  && c.PublishDate <= DateTime.Today
                  && c.Content.ContentType != indie
                  select c;

        var qry2 = from c in qry
                   group c by c.ContentId into grouped
                   select new
                   {
                       Key = grouped.Where(x => x.ContentId == grouped.Key).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Value = grouped.Where(x => x.ContentId == grouped.Key).Select(x => x.Region)
                   };

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            qry2 = from c in qry2
                   where c.Value.Any(x => x.ID == locale)
                   select c;

        var model = qry2.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.PublishDate).Take(QT_FEED).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) && model.Count > 0)
            region = model.FirstOrDefault().Key.Region.CountryEnglish;

        ViewBag.Language = locale;
        ViewBag.FeedTitle = "XBLTOOLS - Full Games";
        ViewBag.FeedDescription = String.Format("{0} - {1}", region, DateTime.Now);

        return View("GlobalFeed", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Arcade(string sort, string locale)
    {
        var page = db.XBLPages.First(x => x.Type == (int)XBLPageType.List);
        using (XBLPageCrawler crawler = new XBLPageCrawler(page, ContentType.Arcade, DownloadType.Game, sort,  locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, crawler.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", crawler.PageContent);
        }
        #region OLDCODE
        //    using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.Arcade, DownloadType.Game, sort, locale))
        //    {
        //        var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
        //        ViewBag.Language = locale;
        //        ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

        //        return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        //    } 
        #endregion
    }

    public ActionResult GamesOnDemand(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.GamesOnDemand, DownloadType.Game, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult IndieGames(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.IndieGames, DownloadType.Game, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult GameDemos(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.GameDemos, DownloadType.GameDemo, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult GameAddons(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.GameAddons, DownloadType.GameAddon, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult GameVideos(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.GameVideos, DownloadType.GameVideo, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult ThemesAndGamerPic(string sort, string locale)
    {
        using (XBLChart p = new XBLChart(ContentType.ThemesAndGamerPic, DownloadType.ThemesAndGamerPic, sort, locale))
        {
            var countrycode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(locale) ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} - ", locale.Split('-')[1].ToUpper());
            ViewBag.Language = locale;
            ViewBag.FeedTitle = String.Format("{0}{1}", countrycode, p.CType.GetDescription());

            return View("Feed", p.ListaRegional);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Changed the Index action to Config and it works. Seems like the problem is with the default implicit "Index", because explicit /Feed/Index works too.

Comment: Can you post your routes? It's not really a bug if the host IDE crashes and causes an issue..

Comment: Do you have multiple methods within your Feed controller?  Would you be able to post both the code within the controller and the code that calls it?

Comment: Do you deploy it to IIS or do you run it on local development server?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Development Server.

Comment: UPDATE: Other actions are failing! I'm doing nothing! Seems VS2010 crashes and just make something useless on the project. I'll try to reset my VS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your routes need the following route adding?

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Feed",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Feed", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```